# ¿Como imprimir un array de punteros sin conocer su tamaño?

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy empezando con los punteros en C, y me está costando algo más de la cuenta. Me gustaría imprimir un puntero que apunta a una zona de memoria de números enteros.

En el programa principal tengo lo siguiente

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int tamano = 10, i = 0;
    int *x = (int*) calloc(tamano, sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
        x[i] = i+1;
    }

    imprimirPuntero(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Y en el procedimiento tengo lo siguiente

```
void imprimirPuntero(int *ptr){
    int i = 0;

    printf("Valores: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
    }
}
```

Así que mi pregunta verdaderamente es... ¿Como se de cuantas posiciones es el puntero, sin pasarle dicho tamaño en el procedimiento?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En estos casos, solo tienes 3 opciones **reales**, mas una 4ª de *bonus*:

1. Pasar el tamaño como argumento a la función.

Según indicas, no puedes/quieres usar esta opción:

```
void imprimirPuntero( const int *ptr, size_t sz ) {
  printf( "Valores: " );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
    printf( "%d ", ptr[i] );
  }
}
```

2. Pasar a la función un puntero que indique una posición conocida.

Lo normal es pasar un puntero al elemento inmediatamente posterior al último. No obstante, nada te impide pasar un puntero a, por ejemplo, el penúltimo elemento (salvo complicar un poco mas el código).
Tu función, pasando la posición **inmediantamente posterior** al ultimo, sería así:

```
void imprimirPuntero( const int *beg, const int *end ) {
  printf( "Valores: " );
  while( beg != end ) {
    printf( "%d ", *beg );
    ++beg;
  }
}
```

3. Marcar el final del *arreglo* con un valor concreto.

Es lo que el compilador hace de forma automática con las cadenas de caracteres, usando un `0` para marcar su final. Pues lo mismo, pero adaptado al tipo de dato que estés usando. Y, claro está, el compilador **no lo hará por tí**, tendrás que poner ese valor *a mano* en la última posición.

```
void imprimirPuntero( const int *beg, int mark ) {
  printf( "Valores: " );
  while( *beg != mark ) {
    printf( "%d ", *beg );
    ++beg;
  }
}
```

**Bonus**

4. Cuando hacemos un `malloc( )`, `calloc( )`o `realloc( )`, la implementación tiene su forma de gestionar la memoria. Normalmente, justo antes de la dirección que nos devuelven, se sitúan unos datos *de control*, **dependientes de la implementación**; en la `libc`, esa estructura de control *puede* ser un simple `size_t` (depende de ciertas opciones de configuración de la propia `libc`). Tu función, suponiendo que tu implementación use un `size_t` como tipo de control:

   ```
   void imprimirPuntero( const int *ptr ) {
     size_t sz = *( ( (size_t *)ptr ) - 1 );
     printf( "Valores: " );
     for( size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
       printf( "%d ", ptr[i] );
     }
   }
   ```

Esta última opción no es 100% fiable; por cuestiones de rendimiento, la librería suele reservar **mas** *bytes* de los necesarios. Pero es bueno saber que existe esta posibilidad :-)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo se de cuantas posiciones es el puntero, sin pasarle dicho tamaño en el procedimiento?

No lo sabes, tu pregunta es tan imposible de responder como *¿Cómo se la edad de una persona si no conozco su fecha de nacimiento?*.

---

Si quieres conocer la cantidad de elementos a las que apunta un puntero, o las conoces de antemano (explícito) o las deduces al momento (implícito).

Para conocer el tamaño de manera explícita tienes el problema que ya conoces: debes facilitar el tamaño junto con el puntero.

Para conocer el tamaño de manera implícita debes marcar el final de los elementos con algún código especial (como hacen las cadenas de caracteres con el carácter nulo `\0`); supongamos que en tu código de ejemplo tu puntero nunca apunta a valores negativos, podríamos usar (por ejemplo) `-1` como marca de final:

```
int main(){

    int tamano = 10, i = 0;
    // Pedimos un elemento adicional para guardar la marca de final
    //                                        vvvv
    int *x = (int*) calloc(tamano, sizeof(int) + 1);

    for(i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
        x[i] = i+1;
    }
    x[tamaño] = -1; // marcamos el final

    imprimirPuntero(x);

    return 0;
}

void imprimirPuntero(int *ptr){
    int i = 0;

    printf("Valores: ");
    // Imprime valores hasta encontrar la marca de final
    //                vvvvvvvv
    for(int *v = ptr; *v != -1; ++v){
        printf("%d ", *v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Super relacionado: https://github.com/Snaipe/libcsptr

Answer (score 2):

Ya te han dado una respuesta bastante completa y bien argumentada.

La realidad es que de forma nativa C no establece un fin de vector como en otros lenguajes, solo en cadenas de caracteres como te han dicho anteriormente.

Por ejemplo en C# al declarar un vector, con la propiedad Length sabemos cual es el tamaño de dicho vector.

En C al realizar:

```
int* v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
int v2[3];
```

En cualquiera de las dos opciones, a nivel memoria (ejemplo) veríamos algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sí posteriormente se realizará el recorrido de cualquiera de los dos vectores en una función.

```
void recorrervector(int *v);
```

Sí no se establece alguna regla como han dicho anteriormente por ejemplo elegir un valor del espectro de los enteros para designarlo como indicador de final del vector.
El recorrido del vector pararía hasta encontrarse con un Segmentation Fault o algún error parecido, porque empezaríamos recorriendo las posiciones de memoria reservadas en este caso hasta la posición que contiene el 567891 y luego seguiría con posiciones de memorias no reservadas, que en el mejor de los casos podríamos manipular pero otro proceso también podría manipularlo.

Al inicio especifique de forma nativa, porque quizá exista alguna librería o estándar para manipulación de vectores que brinde una capa de abstracción y permite realizar lo solicitado.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

> > Así que mi pregunta verdaderamente es... ¿Como se de cuantas posiciones es el puntero, sin pasarle dicho tamaño en el procedimiento?

En sí, no es posible calcular el tamaño del array durante la ejecución de una función, sin embargo, lo que si podríamos hacer, es envolver el *puntero* (el que apunte al *array*) adentro de una estructura, como por ejemplo:

```c
typedef struct 
{
    int* x;
    int length;
}ArrayInt;
```

El miembro `x` me da acceso al contenido del *array* y en `length` guardaremos el tamaño del array. Esta asignación la haremos cuando creemos el *array* dinámico y eso lo podríamos hacer por medio de una función:

```c
void createArray(ArrayInt*, int);
```

El primer parámetro apunta a una estructura de tipo `ArrayInt` y en el segundo se recibe el tamaño del vector.

Y listo, cada vez que queramos hacer alguna operación a través de una función, simplemente debe tener un parámetro que reciba la dirección base de la estructura `ArrayInt` y de esa forma tendremos acceso a la longitud del *array*.

Por ejemplo, una operación podría ser imprimir los elementos del *array*:

```c
void imprimirArray(ArrayInt* ai)
{
    printf("Valores: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < ai->length; i++)
        printf("%d ", ai->x[i]);
}
```

No necesitamos un segundo parámetro para que guarde la longitud del array, simplemente debemos acceder al miembro `length` de la estructura `ArrayInt` y listo.

**Ejemplo completo**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int* x; //Un puntero que apunta al array.
    int length; //Aquí almacenamos la longitud del array.
}ArrayInt;

//Para imprimir el contenido del array.
void imprimirArray(ArrayInt*);
//Para crear el array en memoria.
void createArray(ArrayInt*, int);

int main(void)
{
    int tamano = 10;
    ArrayInt ai;
    //Aquí creamos un array de 10 enteros.
    createArray(&ai, tamano);
    //Asignamos valores al array.
    for(int i = 0; i < ai.length; i++)
        ai.x[i] = i+1;
    
    //Imprimimos el array.
    imprimirArray(&ai);
    
    //Liberamos el array.
    free(ai.x);
    return 0;
}

void imprimirArray(ArrayInt* ai)
{
    printf("Valores: ");
    //Para saber la longitud del array solo basta con acceder al miembro "length".
    for(int i = 0; i < ai->length; i++)
        printf("%d ", ai->x[i]);
}

void createArray(ArrayInt* ai, int size)
{
    ai->x = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    ai->length = size;
}
```