# ¿Es necesario poner el caracter nulo ('\0') en una matriz en C?

Tags: array, c, matriz

En C, en los `vectores`, hace falta colocar el caracter `\0` al final de un `vector` o `array unidimensional`.

Ej:

```
int a[4];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
a[3]='\0'
```

Mi pregunta es si hace falta poner esto también en un `array multidimensional` o `matriz`, de dos o mas dimensiones.

Ej:

```
int a[2][2];
a[0][0]=0;
a[0][1]=1;
a[1][0]=1;
a[1][1]=2;
a[2][0]=2;
a[0][2]=2;
a[2][1]=3;
a[1][2]=3;
a[2][2]='\0';
```

¿O no haría falta?:

```
int a[2][2];
a[0][0]=0;
a[0][1]=1;
a[1][0]=1;
a[1][1]=2;
a[2][0]=2;
a[0][2]=2;
a[2][1]=3;
a[1][2]=3;
a[2][2]=4;
```

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: No es necesario ni lo debes hacer. El caracter nulo marca el final de un array de caracteres pero no de enteros. Si lo que quieres es recorrer el array de enteros sin conocer su longitud, debes crear tus propios [wrappers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/377536/105299). Por cierto, no olvides de [marcar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) que resolvio tu problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> En C, en los vectores, hace falta colocar el caracter \0 al final de un vector o array unidimensional.

Esta afirmación es total y completamente **falsa**.

Solo sería válida en el caso de las cadenas de caracteres y tiene su razón de ser: Identificar cuándo acaba la cadena de caracteres.

Otra alterativa podría ser añadir la longitud de la cadena al inicio del array, pero entonces la manipulación de las cadenas de caracteres sería más tediosa ...

> Mi pregunta es si hace falta poner esto también en un array multidimensional o matriz, de dos o mas dimensiones.

No, obviamente, si estás declarando una matriz de enteros **no tienes que reservar espacio** para los `\0`.

```
int array[3][2] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, {4, 5, 6}};
```

Además, si lo piensas bien, `\0` es equivalente a `0` (solo que en 8 bits en vez de en 32). Así pues, si el `\0` limitase cualquier array, no podrías programar una matriz nula en C

> ¿O no haría falta?:

Ten cuidado, en esos ejemplos **estás escribiendo fuera del array**

Estás declarando una matriz de 2x2, es decir con capacidad para 4 enteros:

```
int a[2][2];
```

Pero estás escribiendo **9 números**:

```
a[0][0]=0;    // 1
a[0][1]=1;    // 2
a[1][0]=1;    // 3
a[1][1]=2;    // 4
a[2][0]=2;    // 5
a[0][2]=2;    // 6
a[2][1]=3;    // 7
a[1][2]=3;    // 8
a[2][2]='\0'; // 9
```

Al declarar un array o una matriz de tamaño `n`, los elementos serán accesibles a través de los índices (0, n-1), es decir **no debes acceder** al elemento `a[n]` porque esa posición de memoria no pertenece a `a`.

El problema aquí es que C no verifica los límites del array, el compilador te deja escribir y leer donde quieras... pero el Sistema Operativo no es tan permisivo y, si intentas acceder a memoria que no te pertenece te va a parar los pies matando tu proceso.

Y si el Sistema Operativo no mata tu proceso es porque estás accediendo a memoria que te pertenece ... vale, pero es que en esa posición de memoria puede estar otra variable diferente, y estás cambiando su valor sin saber qué variable es. Esto suele traducirse en que la aplicación se empieza a volver errática... algo lógico y normal ya que has alterado valores de variables que no venían a cuento.

Comment: Vale, no me había enterado bien xD. Y ¿existen las cadenas de mas de una dimensión?

Comment: @ByRussX no, podrías tener un array de cadenas de caracteres ... pero no es una cadena de caracteres de varias dimensiones ...

Comment: Y en esos arrays es necesario usar el caracter nulo??

Comment: @ByRussX el caracter nulo es única y exclusivamente para finalizar cada cadena de caracteres... si tienes un array de cadenas de caracteres, cada cadena de caracteres tendrá su propio caracter nulo al final de dicha cadena

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Es necesario poner el caracter nulo ('\0') en una matriz en C?

### No.

---

Estás confundiendo conceptos.

1. Estás trabajando con formaciones<sup>1</sup>, no con matrices. Las matrices por definición son grupos de datos agrupados en varias dimensiones.
2. Estás trabajando con formaciones de enteros (`int`), por lo que no tiene sentido guardar datos que no sean enteros, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, ... son enteros, `'\0'` es un caracter<sup>2</sup>.
3. El caracter nulo (`'\0'`) se usa para marcar el final de cadenas de caracteres, no tiene ninguna semántica en otro tipo de formaciones.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>En C los caracteres (`char`) son tipos aritméticos igual que los enteros (`int`), pero conceptualmente no son el mismo dato.

Answer (score 5):

Ni en los vectores ni en los arrays multidimensionales hace falta poner ningún 0 al final, como norma general. Depende de si la función que va a manejar ese vector espera ese 0 o no.

El problema nace de que cuando pasas un vector como parámetro a una función, lo que la función recibe es la dirección en la que *comienza* ese vector, pero a menos que se lo indiques tú de alguna otra forma, no sabe dónde *termina*.

Por ejemplo, imagina una función que tiene que contar cuántos elementos toman un cierto valor dentro del vector que recibe como parámetro. Por ejemplo, la función se podría invocar con la sintaxis `contar(vector, 1)` para contar cuántos elementos valen 1.

La función sería algo así:

```
int contar(int vector[], int dato) {
  int contador = 0;

  for (int i=0; i< ???; i++) {
     if (vector[i] == dato) contador++;
  }
  return contador;
}
```

El problema es que he tenido que poner un `???` que no sé cómo resolver porque desde dentro de la función no puedo saber cuántos elementos tiene el vector.

Para resolver este problema una solución típica suele ser pasarle a la función otro parámetro que indique la longitud del vector. En ese caso la función sería así:

```
int contar(int vector[], int size, int dato) {
  int contador = 0;

  for (int i=0; i< size; i++) {
     if (vector[i] == dato) contador++;
  }
  return contador;
}
```

Y la invocaría con algo como `contar(vector, 4, 1)` (en un ejemplo en el que el vector tiene 4 elementos). Esta solución **no requiere poner a `\0` el elemento final**.

Otra idea puede ser, en lugar de pasarle cuántos elementos tiene el vector, marcar de alguna forma cuál es su último elemento, por ejemplo con lo del `\0`. En ese caso la función operaría de diferente forma, usando un bucle `while` en vez de un `for`. Así:

```
int contar(int vector[], int dato) {
  int contador = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (vector[i] != '\0') {
    if (vector[i]==dato) contador++;
  }
  return contador;
}
```

Pero hay un par de problemas en esta implementación. Lo primero, estás usando el valor `'\0'` como "marca" de final. Ese valor conceptualmente es de tipo `char` pero lo estás metiendo en un elemento que debería ser de tipo `int`. Aunque conceptualmente sería un error, el compilador no pone problemas porque al final los `char` se almacenan como secuencias de bits, al igual que los `int`. El segundo problema es que el carácter `\0` se codifica con la secuencia de bits `00000000`, que visto como `int` es el cero. Es decir, estás usando el cero como marca de "no hay más elementos". Esto no es buena idea porque entonces el vector no podrá contener ningún elemento de valor 0, ya que tan pronto como aparezca el primer 0 se considerará que el vector ha terminado.

Por estas razones no se usa un terminador en los vectores, sino que es más común pasar como parámetro su longitud. Otra cosa son las cadenas de caracteres, que se implementan como vectores de `char`. En ellas sí que tiene sentido usar un terminador `'\0'` porque para empezar es del tipo correcto (`char`) y además el valor binario `00000000` corresponde al ASCII NULO, que es un carácter que no puede formar parte de un texto, con lo que no hay ambigüedad. De hecho la biblioteca estándar C usa este mecanismo en todas las funciones de manejo de cadenas.

### Arrays bidimensionales

Respecto a los arrays bidimensionales la cosa se complica, ya que si bien ocurre lo mismo que con los vectores (se pasa dónde comienza el array pero no dónde termina), además el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de cada fila del array para que, cuando intentas acceder a otra fila, sepa cuántas posiciones de memoria debe avanzar, ya que al final el array bidimensional se almacena en memoria en posiciones contiguas.

Por ejemplo considera un array de 2 filas y 3 columnas, que tiene los siguientes datos:

```
int a[2][3] = {
                {1,2,3}, 
                {4,1,6}
              };
```

Estos datos en realidad se almacenarán contiguos en memoria, ya que la memoria es unidimensional, y estarían por tanto así:

```
Dirección de inicio del array --> | 0001 |
                                  | 0002 |
                                  | 0003 |
                                  | 0004 |
                                  | 0001 |
                                  | 0006 |
```

De modo que `a[0][0]` irá al elemento que está en la dirección de inicio del array, y obtendrás 0001. `a[0][1]` se referirá a la posición siguiente y obtendrás 0002. Pero si quieres ir a la siguiente fila con la expresión `a[1][0]` el programa deberá en realidad acceder a la dirección de inicio más 3 para obtener el 0004 que hay allí.

De forma general cuando intentes acceder a `a[x][y]` se le sumará a la dirección de inicio del array la cantidad `3*x + y` (y el 3 sale de que cada fila tiene 3 elementos).

Por tanto para poder acceder a las diferentes filas el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de cada fila. Por ello en una función que trabaje con arrays bidimensionales debes declarar el tamaño de sus filas (número de columnas) en la propia declaración del parámetro, escribiendo algo como `int array[][3]`. El primer valor (que sería el número de filas) no es necesario especificarlo y se pone  `[]`, por la misma razón que no se especifica el número de elementos de un vector cuando pasas uno: porque el compilador no lo necesita para acceder a los datos. Tú sí lo necesitarás para saber cuándo dejar de iterar, y deberás por tanto pasarlo como un parámetro adicional.

Así por ejemplo la siguiente función sirve para contar cuántos elementos del array bidimensional toman un cierto valor:

```
int contar_array(int array[][3], int num_filas, int dato) {
  int contador = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<num_filas; i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<3; j++) {
      if (array[j][i] == dato) contador++;
    }
  }
  return contador;
}
```

Puedes probar su correcto funcionamiento con algo como:

```
int main(){
  int datos[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,1,6}};
  printf("%d\n", contar_array(datos, 2, 1));
}
```

que imprimirá 2.