# ArregloEnteros Punteros C

Tags: array, c, punteros

Hola chicos buenos dias necesito ayuda con un ejercicio de la facultad que no entiendo, asi va el ejercicio:

```
typedef struct {
int* direccion;
int capacidad;
} ArregloEnteros;
```

donde la idea es dar una definicion alternativa de los arreglos enteros,
`int array[10]` ahora se va a representar como

```
ArregloEnteros array;
```

donde `array.capacidad = 10` y `array.direccion` tiene la dirección de un bloque de memoria de tamaño `10*sizeof(int);`

Dicho todo eso ahora debo hacer una función:

```
ArregloEnteros* arreglo_enteros_crear(int capacidad);
```

la cual la defini asi:

```
ArregloEnteros* arreglo_enteros_crear(int capacidad) {
    ArregloEnteros *puntetoArray;
    puntetoArray->capacidad = capacidad;
    puntetoArray->direccion = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacidad);
    return puntetoArray;
}
```

y cuando la llamo al main me da un error Violación de segmento (`core` generado), yo quería saber que estoy haciendo mal.

la llamada al `main` es la siguiente:

```
int main() {
    ArregloEnteros* array = arreglo_enteros_crear(5);
    printf("\n%p\n",array->direccion);
    printf("%d\n",array->capacidad);

    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama *Wrapper*, que significa envolver el array dentro de una estructura (o *clase*), aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/377536/105299

Answer (score 4):

Fíjate que empiezas declarando un puntero:

```
ArregloEnteros *puntetoArray;
```

Luego para que este puntero *apunte* a un objeto válido tienes que usar `malloc`:

```
puntetoArray = (ArregloEnteros*)malloc(sizeof(ArregloEnteros));
```

Pero claro, realmente no es necesario que `puntetoArray` sea un puntero, podrías crear el objeto por valor:

```
ArregloEnteros arreglo_enteros_crear(int capacidad) {
    ArregloEnteros puntetoArray;
    puntetoArray.capacidad = capacidad;
    puntetoArray.direccion = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacidad);
    return puntetoArray;
}
```

Comment: Dale muchisimas gracias, si pero debo usar obligatoriamente que la funcion me devuelva un puntero, asi que usare malloc para inicializarlo, muchisimas gracias